# Inserting data from user_table into currency_table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, `currency_types`, `userdb`, and `user_currency`.

`userdb` has currency fields (`gold`, `sapphires`, `amethysts`, `garnets`, and `pkeys`). I want to move the data in those currency fields into the `user_currency` table. But the `user_currency` table has the fields `currency_id`, and `value` fields. The `currency_id` field is related to the `currency`types`.`id` field.

I thought I could do it by making a `while` loop for each currency but I can't think of how to finish it and there must be a better way of doing it that I am just not seeing.

I know `mysql_*` is deprecated. The site is being recoded to use MySQLi so there is no point in mentioning it.

`currency_types` table:

```
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `currency_types` LIMIT 0, 25 ;

id  name
1   Gold
2   Sapphires
3   Amethysts
4   Garnets
5   Keys
6   F. Stones
7   Silk
8   Leather
9   Copper
10  Cotton
11  Iron
12  Potions
13  Silver
14  Brass
15  Steel
16  Adamantine
```

`user_currency` table:

```
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `user_currency` LIMIT 0, 25 ;

id  user_id  currency_id  value
```

`userdb` table:

```
SQL query: SELECT `id`, `gold`, `sapphires`, `amethysts`, `garnets`, `pkeys` FROM `userdb` WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 0, 25 ;

id  gold    sapphires   amethysts   garnets pkeys
1   301518  1370        946         82      272
```

**PHP:** (Can't figure out how to get the `currency_id` field)

```
$gold_query=mysql_query('SELECT `id`, `gold` FROM `userdb`');
while($gold=mysql_fetch_array($gold_query))
{
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
        SELECT `id`, `gold`
            FROM `userdb`
        WHERE `id`='.$user['id']);
}
```

Comment: you do want `values` to contain non-CSV right ? please say yes

Comment: @Drew Yes. There should be one row per currency in the `user_currency` table. However, that seems like a lot of rows.  16 rows per user. I've been thinking about making the field hold json data `{"currency_id":1, "value":1000}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A one time shot, no PHP loop or PHP at all, run from a mysql GUI or whatnot.

If you want ones with value=0, drop the where clause on each.

```
INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
select id,'gold',gold from userdb where gold<>0;

INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
select id,'sapphires',sapphires from userdb where sapphires<>0;

INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
select id,'amethysts',amethysts from userdb where amethysts<>0;

INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
select id,'garnets',garnets from userdb where garnets<>0;

INSERT INTO `user_currency` (`user_id`, `currency_id`, `value`)
select id,'pkeys',pkeys from userdb where pkeys<>0;
```

It assumes user_currency.id is an auto_inc and therefore not provided in the insert stmt.